# При Parallel.For закрывается программа

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var before = DateTime.Now;
        double a = 5;
        Random rand = new Random();
        double d = 0;//theta1
        double m = 0;//phi1
        double f = 0;
        double g = 0;//theta2
        double h = 0;//phi2
        double i1 = 0;
        double k = 0;
        int l = 0;
        Parallel.For(0, 90, (ii) =>
        {
            double i = ii;
            for (double j = 0; j < 360; j += 1 * 90 / (90 - i))
            {
                dllsub(ref a, ref i, ref j, out d, out m, out f, out g, out h, out i1, out k, out l);
                if (g > 84 && g < 86) List.Add(project(d, m, g, h, 1000, Time(m - h, f, a)));
            }
        });
        textBox2.Text = "Done; " + List.Count;
        var spendTime = DateTime.Now - before;
        label1.Text = spendTime.ToString();
    }
```

Здравствуйте, проблема заключается в том, что при попытке использовать Parallel.for форма закрывается. Как это можно исправить? 
Вот таким for был изначально:

```
for (double i = 0; i < 90; i += 1)
        {
            for (double j = 0; j < 360; j += 1 * 90/(90 - i))
            {
                dllsub(ref a, ref i, ref j, out d, out m, out f, out g, out h, out i1, out k, out l);
                if (g > 84 && g < 86) List.Add(project(d, m, g, h, 1000, Time(m - h, f, a)));
            }
        }
```

Вот весь проект:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("PVFProject6.dll", EntryPoint = "dllsub_", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]//CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
    static extern int dllsub(ref double r_0, ref double theta_0, ref double phi_0, out double theta_out1, out double phi_out1, out double time_out1,
                 out double theta_out2, out double phi_out2, out double time_out2, out double Energy, out int Rc);
    List<double[]> List = new List<double[]>();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public double[] project(double theta1, double phi1, double theta2, double phi2, double a, double time)
    {
        double x1 = 10 * a * Math.Sin(theta1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.Cos((phi1 - phi2) * Math.PI / 180);
        double y1 = 10 * a * Math.Sin(theta1 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.Sin((phi1 - phi2) * Math.PI / 180);
        double z1 = 10 * a * Math.Cos(theta1 * Math.PI / 180);

        double x2 = 11 * a * Math.Sin(theta2 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.Cos(0 * Math.PI / 180);
        double y2 = 11 * a * Math.Sin(theta2 * Math.PI / 180) * Math.Sin(0 * Math.PI / 180);
        double z2 = 11 * a * Math.Cos(theta2 * Math.PI / 180);

        double x = (x2 - 11 * a * (x2 - x1) / a) * Math.Cos(theta2 * Math.PI / 180);
        double y = y2 - 11 * a * (y2 - y1) / a;
        double[] A = new double[] { x, y, time };
        return A;
    }
    public double Time(double phi1, double time1, double r0)
    {
        return time1 - phi1 / 360 * 2 * Math.PI * (Math.Pow(2 * r0, 3 / 2) + 0.9981);
    }
    public int MyCount(List<double[]> L)
    {
        int k = 0;
        bool inc = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < List.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < List.Count; j++) if (L[j] == L[i] && i != j) inc = false;
            if (inc) k++;
            inc = true;
        }
        return k;
    }
    public void TimeSort(ref List<double[]> A)
   {
       double h = 0;
       for (int i = 1; i < A.Count; i++)
       {
           if (A[i][2] < A[i - 1][2])
           {
               h = A[i][0];
               A[i][0] = A[i - 1][0];
               A[i - 1][0] = h;

               h = A[i][1];
               A[i][1] = A[i - 1][1];
               A[i - 1][1] = h;

               h = A[i][2];
               A[i][0] = A[i - 1][2];
               A[i - 1][2] = h;
           }
       }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var before = DateTime.Now;
        double a = 5;
        Random rand = new Random();
        double d = 0;//theta1
        double m = 0;//phi1
        double f = 0;
        double g = 0;//theta2
        double h = 0;//phi2
        double i1 = 0;
        double k = 0;
        int l = 0;
        Parallel.For(0, 90, (ii) =>
        {
            double i = ii;
            for (double j = 0; j < 360; j += 0.1 * 90 / (90 - i))
            {
                dllsub(ref a, ref i, ref j, out d, out m, out f, out g, out h, out i1, out k, out l);
                if (g > 84 && g < 86) List.Add(project(d, m, g, h, 1000, Time(m - h, f, a)));
            }
        });
        textBox2.Text = "Done; " + List.Count;
        var spendTime = DateTime.Now - before;
        label1.Text = spendTime.ToString();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Refresh();
        textBox2.Text = "" + MyCount(List);
        richTextBox1.Text = "";
        foreach (double[] a in List) richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + (int)Math.Round(a[1] * 100 + 800) + "\t" + (int)Math.Round(a[0] * 100 + 300) + "\t" + Math.Round (a[2]) + "\n"; 
    }

    private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (double[] a in List) e.Graphics.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(40, 0, 130, 180)), (int)Math.Round(a[1] * 50 + 300), (int)Math.Round(a[0] * 4000 + 300), 8, 8);
    }
}
```

dllsub - процедура из библиотеки, написанной на fortran'e

Comment: `dllsub`, `project` ?? `List` - потоко-безопасный?

Comment: Собственно, вот Вам и ответ: `lock(List) { List.Add(...); }`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!